# @ViewChild is undefined in Angular 6 Inheritance

Tags: angular, viewchild, angular-decorator

Im using angular 6 to implement below example. When do this way ended up with Undefined Error while using @ViewChild in parent. Here is the code snippet,

Base Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp1',
    styleUrls: ['landing.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: 'bcomponent.html'
})

export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild(QComponent) public questionModal: QComponent;

    public openQModal(): void {
         setTimeout(function() {
            this.questionModal.openModal();
        }.bind(this), 200);
    }   
}
```

Child Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp2',
    styleUrls: ['ccomponent.scss'],
    templateUrl: 'ccomponent.html'
})

export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor({super ();})

}
```

When I call openQModal() from bcomponent.html it works fine but when I call the same method from ccomponent.html it fails with "undefined" error.

bcomponent.html

```
 <div class="fd-message-block--buttons-container">
                                <button #questionnaireButton
                                        id="questionnaireButton"
                                        class="fd-button fd-button_orange fd-button_16"
                                        (click)="openQModal()"
                                        [innerHtml]="landing.buttonText | safeHtml"></button>                        
</div>
```

ccomponent.html

```
 <a id="btn-back" (click)="openQModal()">Click Here!!</a>
```

Comment: BTW you don't need to call an empty super() constructor in Angular, or any empty contstructors. Furthermore, `constructor({super ();})` is not what you want anyway, it would be written `constructor(){super();}`.

Comment: Sorry, it was type. i just kept block of code for explaining the issue. Thx

Comment: @Sathish Show us the templates.

Comment: Also what _calls_ `openQModal()` ?

Comment: @zhulien /msanford2 Just say, a button will trigger on-click event call to openQModal() from html

Comment: could you please provide your html part as well ?

Comment: @Sathish You have to show us _everything_ we need to diagnose this problem, please. That includes a real [mcve] and the template logic. The problem is obvious: you call `.openModal()` too early in the parent's lifecycle, before your `QComponent` has been initialized and so the ViewChild can't find it. That timer is a code smell. Check out [Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: @Sathish, Please provide full code snippet or html code.

Comment: I have added the snippet above for your reference.

Comment: @msanford As parent will be loaded first before even child created right? If yes, how does only viewChild components are undefined but other elements are accessible ?

Comment: @Sathish Please, post the whole view template for both components. We're not even sure if you're actually referencing 'QComponent' in your 'ccomponent's view.

Comment: @zhulien - There is no mentioning of any component in any of views. its just simple html elements. As file is classified so i can share only snippet for now. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @Sathish How are you using '@ViewChild(QComponent)' in 'BaseComponent' when you are not referencing 'QComponent' in the view template? Or maybe, like I stated earlier, this is the exact problem.

Comment: Take account that, when you call to openModal, the Qcomponent must be "exist". If you use *ngIf, Angular can not find it. See a quick example in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-averux?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. If you click when Hello is visible you see in console "12345"

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your time and suggestions. Finally it is a problem of *ngIf.